# MAMP to Live Server :: Fatal Error Class 'wpdb' not found in load.php

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I'm trying to move my site from MAMP to the live server and I'm getting this error:

Fatal error: Class 'wpdb' not found in /data/*folder_name*/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404

I went through the basic steps of moving everything. Created the Database, Imported my database, updated the wp-config.php and uploaded all of my files so I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm not even sure where to start.

Here is the code in load.php

```
/**
 * Load the database class file and instantiate the `$wpdb` global.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @global wpdb $wpdb The WordPress database class.
 */
function require_wp_db() {
    global $wpdb;

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/wp-db.php' );
    if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) )
        require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' );

    if ( isset( $wpdb ) )
        return;

    $wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );<--Line 404
}
```

Comment: Seems like a path issue, as WP uses some different constants to load in that WPDB class. Did you ever hardcode the server file path in any of your config files by chance? Your folder structure will have changed of course on the live server, so that could cause this issue.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking the issue is but I'm not sure where it's getting that path from. I took a look at line 404 of load.php and I see this `/**
 * Load the database class file and instantiate the '$wpdb' global.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @global wpdb $wpdb The WordPress database class.
 */
function require_wp_db() {
 global $wpdb;

 require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/wp-db.php' );
 if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) )
  require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' );

 if ( isset( $wpdb ) )
  return;

 $wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
}`

Comment: I'd take a look over your wp-config.php file, top to bottom -- Sometimes the WP_CONTENT_DIR or WP_CONTENT_URL constant (or others) gets overridden in there, and can cause this problem. Basically just look for anything that defines a specific path that would exist on your MAMP site but not live

Comment: I don't see a WP_CONTENT_DIR or a WP_CONTENT_URL in my wp-config file anywhere. I downloaded the wp-config of another site that is up and running on the same server and everything is the same except for the DB credentials and the table prefix. This is the only thing I can find that has anything to do w/ path `if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: Did you change URLs in the database options table from the localhost to the live domain?

Comment: yes and just double checked to make sure and they're changed.

Comment: I assume since I'm getting that error it is connecting to the database correct?

Comment: You will always get the "Can't connect to Database error" if everything else is OK except database credentials; but it sounds like you might not be getting that far becuase of paths or missing files. Be sure to reupload all core WP files and folders.

Comment: Welp. I don't know what the problem was but I deleted the wp-admin and wp-includes folder and uploaded a fresh download and it works now. Thanks for looking into this @markratledge

Comment: Thanks to you to @GregBurkett

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with the files loaded and nothing else. :-(